# How do I disable RadButton from server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have this button in my aspx file.

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnEnable" OnClick="btnEnable_Click" runat="server" ToolTip="enable"
                                Text="Enable" Enabled="false" Icon-PrimaryIconUrl="~/images/icon.png">
</telerik:RadButton>
```

I am disabling it on client-side like this :

```
btnEnable.set_enabled(false);
```

I want to add server-side code in my aspx.cs. So when item is selected in grid, I want this button to be disabled from server-side.

function looks like this

```
protected void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(someLogic){btnEnable must be disabled}
}
```

If it helps, this button can be called after item is selected in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can add ToggleStates:

```
MyButton.ToggleType = ButtonToggleType.CheckBox;
MyButton.ButtonType = RadButtonType.ToggleButton;
MyButton.ToggleStates.Add("Selected");
MyButton.ToggleStates.Add("Unselected");
MyButton.Checked= false; //set to unselected
```